# Error in database connection: Database "dbname" does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, dbconnection

I have created a python file app.py and included the code to connect to a db I created in postgresql as follows: -

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    user='postgres',
    password='1234',
    host='localhost',
    port='5432',
    database='bubbleformation'  
)

cursor = conn.sursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM bubbleformation')

for row in cursor: print(row)
conn.close()
```

This was as instructed in [this medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/connecting-python-to-oracle-sql-server-mysql-and-postgresql-ea1e4523b1e9)

However, when I try to execute this python file in the terminal, I get the below error: -

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "app.py", line 8, in
>   
>       port='5432'      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 130, in
>   connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "bubbleformation" does not exist

I have created a table named "bubbleformation" and it can be viewed in the psql mode through the terminal.

Could anyone please help me understand what should be done? I tried changing the password, and user privileges, but none of them worked for my error.

Comment: did you check if database exist? List the databases `psql -l` and list the tables in bubbleformation `psql -d bubbleformation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create both database and table with the same name "bubbleformation". You've probably created that table in postgres database.

Enter psql as postgres user and call `CREATE DATABASE bubbleformation;`, then connect to it with `\connect bubbleformation`  and then create your table (something like `CREATE TABLE bubbleformation (id int, name text);`).

Comment: Thank you! You are right, "bubbleformation" was the name of the table. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The error is about there not being a database named "bubbleformation", so when you connect to the database in the terminal, whichever database that is is the one you need to specify in the database parameter. When you connect to the database in the terminal, type:

```
SELECT current_database();
```

If it is indeed a database named "bubbleformation" then is must be a different cluster you are connecting to, and therefore a different port.

Disclosure: I am an EnterpriseDB (EDB) employee.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Changing the database name solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to environment error. I was loading the credentials from the .env file. But i mistakenly gave a wrong path.

```py
project_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/scraping') instead of 
project_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/find_my_nearest_store')
load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, '.env'))
```

Hence the Error.